# Structured data validation error: illustration (CreativeWork) inside an Article is not a valid image attribute?

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

I normally tagged illustrations and photographs inside articles as CreativeWork - to credit appropriate authors (creators of visuals).

```
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
  <h1 itemprop="headline">Headline</h1>
  <p itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">by <span itemprop="name">John Public</span></p>

  <figure itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
    <img itemprop="image" src="http://example.com/artwork.jpg" alt="Artwork" />
    <figcaption itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">Illustration by <span itemprop="name">George Smith</span></figcaption>
  </figure>

  <p>Full content of the article.</p>
</article>
```

So far so good. Article has its author as well as the illustration, both properly credited.

However, according to the [Google validation tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/articles), image is a required attribute for Article type, otherwise the code above is not passing the validation. This is not, however, a requirement of the [Article Schema](http://schema.org/Article).

How do I escape code duplication, pass Google Schema validation and still credit both authors and illustrators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schema.org has no required properties, but consumers, like Google Search, may of course require that certain properties are provided for doing something with your data (e.g., showing a Rich Snippet).

If you want to get [Google’s Rich Snippet for Articles](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/articles), you have to provide the properties `headline`, `image`, and `datePublished`.

If the image represents the article (in contrast to an image that is just part of the article, but not representative), you could use the [`image` property](http://schema.org/image) to reference the `ImageObject`¹ from the `Article`.
For that, you just have to add the `itemprop` to the `figure` element:

```html
<figure itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
```

If the image is not representative, you should not use this (in which case you probably don’t get this Article Rich Snippet). To still be able to reference² the image(s) from the `Article`, you could use the [`hasPart` property](http://schema.org/hasPart):

```html
<figure itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
```

---

¹ You are using `CreativeWork`, but if the work is an image, you’d ideally use the sub-type [`ImageObject`](http://schema.org/ImageObject) and its [`contentUrl` property](http://schema.org/contentUrl).

² If you don’t use a property to reference the `ImageObject` from the `Article`, they are in no kind of relation. The [HTML nesting does not affect the Microdata](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/83333/17633) unless you use `itemprop`.